# Laravel relation foreign key pointing to UNIQUE constraint

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

**users table:**

```
id    int primary key, auto increment
r_id  varchar unique
name  varchar
```

**books table:**

```
id       int primary key, auto increment
user_id  foreign key to r_id in users table
name     varchar
```

The relation in User Model:

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Book', 'user_id');
```

By default, `user_id` FOREIGN KEY is pointing to a PRIMARY KEY id. How can i make it pointing to a UNIQUE `r_id`?

**If Only**, `r_id` is primary key, we can pass it with third argument and overriding `$primaryKey` property:

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Book', 'user_id','r_id');
protected $primaryKey = "r_id";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Eloquent orm expect local key to be `id`. To override it you can pass in third argument in relationship.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

```
$this->hasMany('App\Model', 'foreign_key', 'local_key')
```

So, your relation can be

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Book', 'user_id', 'r_id');
```

Update:

I recall, I ran into similar situation recently. Can you try this and revert me back. I will update the answer with details later. Add following method in your User model and test. Thanks

```
public function getRIdAttribute($value)
{
    return $value;
}
```

Comment: doesn't that `local_key` neccessarily be a primary key?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Did the 3rd argument fixed the issue for you?

Comment: `r_id` is actually not a primary key.

Comment: Check line 878 to see what's happening behing the scenes. `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php` Since you've overridden `$primaryKey` that should have worked without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code need to update like:

```
 return $this->hasMany('App\Book');
```

Hope this work for you!

Comment: this assumes `user_id` foreign key pointing to primary key `id`, i want user_id to point to r_id which is unique.

Comment: Please follow this [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)